# Error: Call to a member function on null and Warning: Uninitialized string offset

Tags: php, forms, drupal-8

Currently i'm working on import module for drupal 8, i'm beginner with this cms and most of the time I follow guides, tutorials, code of other similar modules and documentation to create code. When i'm testing my module (by "importing" empty files) i'm getting error and warning like these:

Error: Call to a member function setPermanent() on null in Drupal\customimport\Form\CustomImport->submitForm() (line 82 of modules/custom/customimport/src/Form/CustomImport.php).

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in Drupal\customimport\Form\CustomImport->submitForm() (line 80 of modules/custom/customimport/src/Form/CustomImport.php).

I see both are related to submitForm() method. According to guides over the internet i see there should be no problems with this method the way i have it implemented, even some other modules use very similar, if not identical code for this method as mine. This means there is an error in logic of my method which i'm unable to find, probably because of lack of deeper experience with drupal 8. Here is code of my submitForm() method:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $csv_file = $form_state->getValue('csv_file');

    $file = File::load($csv_file[0]);

    $file->setPermanent();

    $file->save();

    $data = $this->csvImport($file->getFileUri(), ',');
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $operations[] = ['\Drupal\customimport\addImportContent::addImportContentItem', [$row]];
    }

    $batch = array(
        'title' => t('Importing Data...'),
        'operations' => $operations,
        'init_message' => t('Import is starting.'),
        'finished' => '\Drupal\customimport\addImportContent::addImportContentItemCallback',
    );
    batch_set($batch);


}
```

To solve this i've searched some guides, tutorials, other modules and i'm writing here as last resort to find help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the $csv_file is an empty array, so you should add some check code before the variable $csv_file is used.